# Is R an order? Find the minimal, maximal, least, and greatest elements

Tags: matrices, relations, order-theory

[image]

So I think I proved that it's order but check my work because I'm not too sure about it.

(a,a)∈R for all a∈A, therefore it's reflexive.

(a,b)∈R, (b,c)∈R, and (a,c)∈R, therefore it's transitive.

(a,b)∈R and (b,a)∉R unless a=b, therefore it's antisymmetric.

I'm not sure how to find the minimal, maximal, least and greatest elements.

Comment: The heck with matrices.  Draw a diagram.

Comment: I also drew a diagram, but how would I find the minimal, maximal etc. elements out of that?

Comment: What is the definlition of least element?  Try each point to see which are least.

Comment: Least element is below all other elements. Im not sure how to tell which is least because it doesnt give me a relationship like a>b or something

Comment: The matrix gives the order relation of every element to every other element.  Hiw could you have have drawn  a diagram without knowing how the elements are related by the order <=?

Comment: Im looking at the diagram and I think I may have noticed some order. I observed d is at the top, then c and b are both below it and in the same level, then below c is a. Is that correct?

Comment: Not knowing what exactly a  1 means in the matrix and how you are labling the points it is not possible to verify your claim.  However, more or less, it seems it could be correct.

Comment: The question doesnt tell me what 1 means. I actually drew a graph, not a diagram, so I used that to find the order.

Comment: Do you know if my answer is 100% correct?

Comment: It depends upon what a,b,c,d means and how a lattice describes a relation.  With out knowing, it is all guess work.

Comment: What would you put down as an answer?